# CSS background image - responsive image that scales without depending on image size

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, background-image, image-scaling

Im trying to get background image that scales whole image without depending on size of the picture and that fits all screens showing exactly same. I got it to work butafter i changed picture it doesent work anymore. Oh and im using Bootstrap 3.

heres my css:

```
.bg {

    background-image: url(http://pikahinaukset.wpengine.com/wp-  content/uploads/2015/06/coverphoto-e1433360465261.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background: url(http://pikahinaukset.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/coverphoto-e1433360465261.jpg) center center cover no-repeat fixed;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;

}
```

Edited:

heres html http://jsfiddle.net/jw7L2s3y/

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something redundant: background with center and all the stuff then you are doing background-image, background-repeat and all that. It is basically doing the same thing as background: . Remove one of them and i think it is working fine anyways.

[Working Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2r3sevxc/1/)

```
.bg {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(http://pikahinaukset.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/coverphoto-e1433360465261.jpg) ;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;

}
```